# Find all Mongo documents that have 2 or more fields that are equal between documents

Tags: mongodb

Get all documents that have the same value for field1 and the same value for field2:

```
document one: {
   field1: 'value1',
   field2: 'value2',
   uniqField: 'asdf'
} 

document two:  { 
   field1: 'value1',
   field2: 'value2',
   randomField: 'phdl'
}

document three:  { 
   field1: 'value45',
   field2: 'value2',
   arbitraryThing: 60
}

document four:  { 
   field1: 'value7',
   field2: 'value8',
   third: 55
}
document five:  { 
   field1: 'value7',
   field2: 'value8',
   again: 607
}
document six:  { 
   field1: 'value45',
   field2: 'value8',
   another: 607
}
```

UPDATE:

I want to return document one and document two, and also four and five but not document three or six.

So the pseudo-query would look something like

`db.collection.getAllDocumentGroupsWithMatchingFields([field1, field2])  -> [[document one, document two], [document four, document five]]`

My suspicion is that this isn't possible with straight Mongo and would require JS.

Comment: You should be able to do that with $expr.

Answer (score 0):

For two fields

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": ["$field1", "$field2"] } })
```

For more than two fields,

You can have `$and` with all the conditions

Like `eq on field1, field2 AND eq on field1, field3`

```
db.collection.find({$and:[
{ "$expr": 
     { "$eq": ["$field1", "$field2"] } }, 
{ "$expr": 
     { "$eq": ["$field1", "$field3"] } } 
]})
```

OR

1. Use `aggregation`
2. First stage you can have the same condition as in two fields check
3. All documents which matches the second step, passed to this step. Here you compare `field1` with `field3`. Documents which has same value for field1, 2, 3 are passed to the next stage.
4. And so on.

**Update:**

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mz5FfTDA-5f)

You just need normal find with and.

```
db.collection.find({
  field1: "value1",
  field2: "value2"
})
```

Comment: I should have clarified more before I posted. I think what you provided an answer for is if the two fields on the same document are equal. What I want is all the documents in a collection that have the same values for two fields. I'll edit the OP to illustrate.

Comment: I'm realizing how complicated it is to ask this question, which gives me the suspicion that I'm trying to do something the wrong way. My updated version was also misleading.

Thanks for both responses so far. What I really want is a query that returns all documents that match between two or more fields, but where the values for those fields don't match _between_ all the documents.

Comment: I appreciate this back and forth. I'm still fairly green and it helps me to better clarify my questions in future. Also didn't realize there was a Mongo playground. That's fantastic.